# OpenACC - The C++ 'new' operator issue

Tags: c++, new-operator, openacc

The C++ `new` operator seems to be forbidden within OpenACC `routine` region.
I wanted to know why (I've checked the spec for the `routine` directive but I haven't found anything on it).

Here is the code I implemented using OpenACC, it's a basic complex matrix product using my own complex number class (I shrunk my code to make it a bit more readable):

```
class Complex {
  private:
    double* c;
  public:
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex ( )
    {
      c = new double[2];
      #pragma acc enter data copyin(this)
      #pragma acc enter data create(c[:2])
      c[0] = 0.0;
      c[1] = 0.0;
    }
    Complex ( Complex const& z )
    {
      c = new double[2];
      #pragma acc enter data copyin(this)
      #pragma acc enter data create(c[:2])
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
    }
    ~Complex ( )
    {
      #pragma acc exit data delete(c[:2])
      #pragma acc exit data delete(this)
      delete[] c;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator+= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] += z.c[0];
      c[1] += z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator*= ( Complex const z )
    {
      double a(c[0]), b(c[1]);
      c[0] = a*z.c[0] - b*z.c[1];
      c[1] = b*z.c[0] + a*z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
};
#pragma acc routine seq
inline Complexe operator* ( Complex z1, Complex const z2 )
{
  z1 *= z2;
  return z1;
}

int main ( )
{
  Complex A[N][N];
  Complex B[N][N];
  // initialisation of A and B
  Complex C[N][N];
  #pragma acc data copyout(C[:N]) copyin(A[:N],B[:N])
  {
    #pragma acc parallel loop
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      #pragma acc loop
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        Complex accum;
        #pragma acc loop seq
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
          accum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = accum;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that a dynamic array for complex numbers is far from being the best idea but it's just an example.

When I compile with `pgc++` I get this error (coming from my `Complex::Complex()` constructor):

```
PGCC-S-1000-Call in OpenACC region to procedure '_Znam' which has no acc routine information
```

I've read that the `_Znam` procedure is called by `new`.

So I would like to know why it is not possible to use `new` within an OpenACC region and how I can change my code to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why on earth do you use `double* c;` rather than `double r;` and `double i`; for the real and imaginary components? Currently you have to implement the copy constructor, assignment operator, &c, yourself. You may as well chuck your PC out the window.

Comment: Will `Complex::c` ever be a pointer to something else than a `double[2]`? Then why use pointers and dynamic allocation?

Comment: Indeed ^ this doesn't answer the question but your use of dynamic allocation here is entirely silly anyway

Comment: It sounds to me that this problem has nothing to do with the `new` operator, and is instead an issue with the way you're invoking the pgc++ compiler, which is not bringing in the C++ standard library properly. Don't jump to conclusions when performing your diagnosis/research.

Comment: Not really no, I just did some Googling and skimmed the first few items

Comment: Yes yes I know you're all right it is not the best example, but I wanted to provide a simple one. Let's say that my code should work with quaternion as well, so `Complex::c` may point to a `double[4]`. I just want to know more about the incompatibility between new and OpenACC... @BoundaryImposition Oh, interesting thank you, can you be more precise?

Comment: Premature generalisation is the root of all evil. If you *really* need a variable length array, use std::vector<double>

Comment: @virgesmith Thank you for your comment, but it seems that std::vector is not supported by OpenACC (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35047769/7635052)

Comment: Actually the correct solution is a template

Comment: All right I think I should come up with a better example because I might be misunderstanding the comments but it seems that people care more about the optimisation than my question itself... Although it is true that the conception I used is pretty ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, the OpenACC standard doesn't specify support for specific language features.  That is left up to the implementation and will depend upon the target device.  For PGI's implementation of OpenACC targeting NVIDIA GPUs, no, new is not supported from within an OpenACC compute regions.  "malloc" is supported, but I highly recommend not dynamically allocating data from within device code.  Besides having a relatively small heap (currently a default of 8MB but can be increased up to 32MB using the environment variable PGI_ACC_CUDA_HEAPSIZE), having many thousands of threads allocating data can cause a severe performance slow-down.

Below I updated your example using both a fixed size data member and a dynamic data member.  Besides fixing some typos, I removed the "data" directives from the constructor/destructor since "data" directives can only be used in host code.  When using a fixed size data member, the code is straight forward.  With dynamic data members, each individual data members needs to be "attached" (i.e. the member's device address needs to be set in the device object).  The OpenACC standard committee is working on a method to automatically do this, but for now it needs to be done in the program itself.  The method used below, aka manual deep copy, is a PGI extension which will be adopted in the next OpenACC standard, 2.6.

Test 1 Fixed size data member:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _OPENACC
#include <openacc.h>
#endif
#ifndef N
#define N 32
#endif

class Complex {
  private:
    double c[2];
  public:
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex ( )
    {
      c[0] = 0.0;
      c[1] = 0.0;
    }
    Complex ( Complex const& z )
    {
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
    }
    ~Complex ( )
    {
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator+= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] += z.c[0];
      c[1] += z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator*= ( Complex const z )
    {
      double a(c[0]), b(c[1]);
      c[0] = a*z.c[0] - b*z.c[1];
      c[1] = b*z.c[0] + a*z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    void printme() {
       std::cout << c[0] << ":" << c[1] << std::endl;
    }

};
#pragma acc routine seq
inline Complex operator* ( Complex z1, Complex const z2 )
{
  z1 *= z2;
  return z1;
}

int main ( )
{
  Complex A[N][N];
  Complex B[N][N];
  // initialisation of A and B
  Complex C[N][N];
  #pragma acc data copyout(C[:N]) copyin(A[:N],B[:N])
  {
    #pragma acc parallel loop
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      #pragma acc loop
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        Complex accum;
        #pragma acc loop seq
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
          accum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = accum;
      }
    }
  }
  C[0][0].printme();
}
```

Test 2 Dynamic Data Members

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef _OPENACC
#include <openacc.h>
#endif
#ifndef N
#define N 32
#endif

class Complex {
  private:
    double *c;
  public:
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex ( )
    {
      c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
      c[0] = 0.0;
      c[1] = 0.0;
    }
    Complex ( Complex const& z )
    {
      c = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*2);
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
    }
    ~Complex ( )
    {
      free(c);
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] = z.c[0];
      c[1] = z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator+= ( Complex const z )
    {
      c[0] += z.c[0];
      c[1] += z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    #pragma acc routine seq
    Complex& operator*= ( Complex const z )
    {
      double a(c[0]), b(c[1]);
      c[0] = a*z.c[0] - b*z.c[1];
      c[1] = b*z.c[0] + a*z.c[1];
      return *this;
    }
    void printme() {
       std::cout << c[0] << ":" << c[1] << std::endl;
    }
#ifdef _OPENACC
    void acc_create() {
        #pragma acc enter data create(c[0:2])
    }
    void acc_copyin() {
        #pragma acc enter data copyin(c[0:2])
    }
    void acc_delete() {
        #pragma acc exit data delete(c)
    }
    void acc_copyout() {
        #pragma acc exit data copyout(c[0:2])
    }
#endif
};
#pragma acc routine seq
inline Complex operator* ( Complex z1, Complex const z2 )
{
  z1 *= z2;
  return z1;
}

int main ( )
{
  Complex A[N][N];
  Complex B[N][N];
  // initialisation of A and B
  Complex C[N][N];

#ifdef _OPENACC
    #pragma acc enter data create(A[0:N][0:N],B[0:N][0:N],C[0:N][0:N])
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
           A[i][j].acc_copyin();
           B[i][j].acc_copyin();
           C[i][j].acc_create();
      }
    }
#endif

    #pragma acc parallel loop present(A,B,C)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      #pragma acc loop
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        Complex accum;
        #pragma acc loop seq
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
          accum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = accum;
      }
  }
#ifdef _OPENACC
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
           A[i][j].acc_delete();
           B[i][j].acc_delete();
           C[i][j].acc_copyout();
      }
    }
    #pragma acc exit data delete(A[0:N][0:N],B[0:N][0:N],C[0:N][0:N])
#endif
  C[0][0].printme();
}
```

Comment: Great that is exactly what I wanted to know, thank you very much!